# Laravel problem to pass error message from email verification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I would like to ask for help because I don't know how to tell the user that the activation link is incorrect.

I overwrite the verify method, and now, after successful activation, the user receives information. But when the link is invalid gets 403 | Invalid signature.

I have run out of ideas and I would like to change the form of the message to a bootstrap alert displayed on the login page

```
protected $redirectTo = '/login';


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    public function verify(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

        if (!hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }


        if ($user->markEmailAsVerified())
            event(new Verified($user));

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
    }
```

I tried try catch but it didn't work

Anyone know how this can be achieved ?? I am using Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

you can just check if the signature is valid or not then redirect or add a payload.

```
if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
       // do stuff here (return view, redirect etc)
   }
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it still gets 403 even if I use dd ()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try changing the `throw new AuthorizationException;` inside the verify method to add your own logic.